# Simple if statement and scanf not working for me

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char choice[1];
    printf("Do you like oranges? y/n: \n");
    scanf("%s\n", choice);
    if (choice == "y")
        printf("I do too! \n");
    else if (choice == "n")
        printf("Screw you then! \n");
    else
        printf("You did not type it correctly.");
    return 0;
}
```

When it asks me the `scanf("");` portion in my code when it runs, it doesn't continue until I input two things, which causes the `else` function to run.

Example:

```
Do you like oranges? y/n:

y
y

You did not type it correctly.
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. If it compiles, you're not using a C compiler, or you're not using it properly.

Comment: `choice[0]`? Are you sure?

Comment: It does compile? It runs just fine?

Comment: Ahhhhh, I forgot about you need at least 1 because there is the invisible character EDIT -- Same problem though

Comment: scanf is dangerous, especially when used like this. What happens if someone types in "hippopotamous"? Your "choice" buffer is not big enough (even if you made it `choice[2]`. This is a classic source of buffer overrun exploits.

Comment: What do I do then? I'm new to c as I said.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, remove whitespace after `%s` in your `scanf` format

```
scanf("%s", choice);
```

Whitespace in your `scanf` format has special meaning: it directs it to "skip all whitespace", which makes it to continue to read the input stream until the first non-whitespace character is encountered. This is what forces it to wait until you "input two things".

Secondly, string comparison in C is done through `strcmp` function. You cannot compare strings through `==` operator. Either use `strcmp` or make sure you compare only one character. Either this

```
if (strcmp(choice, "y") == 0)
```

or that

```
if (choice[0] == 'y')
```

Thirdly, a string of length 1 will not fit into a buffer of length 1. You need an extra buffer entry for the terminating `\0` character. If you insist on reading hat `y/n` response as a string, you need a buffer of at least 2 characters long. This is still dangerous though, since you can always enter a longer string and overflow the buffer. At least use `%1s` specifier to read the string.

Comment: I fixed the choice[0] and the whitespace. No dice

Comment: @Hunter Kepley: `\n` is also whitespace. In `scanf` it has the same effect as the regular space character.

Comment: It WAS the whitespace!

Answer (score 1):

First thing first... Just get rid of ANY white space characters in scanf's format parameter, unless you want to scan format for any other input beside choice. That being said, scanf can accept white spaces but this means you will be submitting some other parameters.

For example:

```
scanf("%d %c %2f", &SomeDecimal, &SomeChar, &SomeFloat)
```

While it's not an error to not to use & with array parameters in scanf, it's advised to use one.

Don't use `%s`, actually don't use scanf at all to get strings, but uhm..

You're scanning for a string and passing a 1 lengthed array of char which is logically equal to char. So you should declare

```
char choice;
```

and use it in scanf like

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
```

If you insist on `char choice[1]` declaration, then change your scan code to `scanf("%c", &choice[0])` and check `if(choice[0] == 'y')` like.. And totally, you should read carefully what @AndreyT just said in his answer about strings.

Last and the most important thing by me, get a starter level C language book. I guess you're not just new to c but new to programming, too. That book will be very, and very, useful.

Comment: In addition to this (I would also use a char in this case), you can make one state default, often noted with a capital character (Do you like oranges? [y/N], you can use only an if else statement, check for the non default and do everything else in the else:
if(character == 'y') printf("Me too!!\n");
else printf("Really?! why not?");